# How to check decimal value in where clause laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project where users saves the value in decimal format, but when I try to retrieve data from the database, it returns an empty array. Please help me to find the solution or fix the problem. Below is my query.

Min Weight = 2.99

Weight = 3.25

[image]

```
$weight = \App\WeightSettings::where('city_id', $cartItem['city_id'])->where('min_weight', '>=', $weight)->first();
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: how do you set your DB Table? is it set to Decimal too? if not, most DB will just set it as 0

Comment: @zimorok please check the database table structure

Comment: for easy debugging, try to query the DB with raw SQL to check if it really contain any data

Comment: @zimorok it is working if I hit query in the database.

Comment: can you post full query code

Comment: @RobinSingh yes, show your raw SQL query where it is working